# Is there an WCF extension point that is called before UserNamePasswordValidator?

Tags: c#, wcf

I need something to be run before `UserNamePasswordValidator.Validate(username, password)` is called for each WCF request.

I already tried to use an `IDispatchMessageInspector`, but the inspector is called after `UserNamePasswordValidator.Validate`.

Is there an WCF extension point that is called before `UserNamePasswordValidator`?

Comment: Does [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tdevere/archive/2014/10/13/implement-a-usernamepasswordvalidator-for-wcf-service-hosted-in-iis.aspx) help?

Comment: @Christian.K Sry, I don't know how this could help me.

Comment: Depending on what you want to do you can inject your own validation or add some logic before the standard validation.

Comment: @peer That's true, but I thought on not using UserNamePasswordValidator to initialize my configuration, because both are different concerns.

Comment: This sounds like a potential [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) what problem are you trying to solve where you think being able to have a extension point before the validate will solve it?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain In my UserNamePasswordValidator I need to get some configuration values from a database. For doing this I have a dependency that is giving me the configurations. I want the configuration to be loaded exactly one time per web request. So I am looking for something where I could execute my Configuraiton.Initialize method. At the time were UserNamePasswordValidator is executed there is no per request context available.

Answer (score 0):

I once ran into a similar situation. What I ended up doing was implement a custom username/password validator class. I ran the code that I had to, then ran the good ol' username/password validator.

```
public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
{
    // your custom code here...

    // then...
    base.Validate(userName, password);
}
```

As per what you're describing, retrieving configuration values per request could very well be done in this way.

[Check out this MSDN page to see how to implement a custom username/password validator.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa354513(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I assume that you you *want* to use the base.Validate(...), if not then don't use it.